# How to add alb ingress controller to ec2 cluster without aws eks

Tags: kubernetes

i have created two ec2 instances in aws, one is master another one is worker after that i have setup ec2 cluster, deployed the application are working fine, i can able to access using ec2 instance ip with nodeport.
after that i deployed nginx ingress-controller and ingress resource, i cant able to access my application using nginx ingress(NO external ip)
then installed metallb, external ip has allocated but there is no use i mean not able access my app using that ip

is there any way to make it workable without aws eks and aws alb  or ec2 instance with alb(without aws eks ony ec2 instance have cluster)